# mongoose return default value instead of null value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, null

I have a collection with a fields for the first name and the last name that are optional and can be not set at all.

However I need to query the concatenation of them to search for a full name, but if one of the names isn't set then the return value of the concatenation is null.

Is there a way to return/concat a default value (an empty string) in case the name is not set?

I want to do something like:

```
db.User.aggregate([
  {
    $project: { firstName: '$firstName' || '' },
    $project: { lastName: '$lastName' || '' },
    $project: { fullName: { $concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName'] } }
  }
]);
```

or even:

```
db.User.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      firstNames: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $exists: [false] },
            then: '',
            else: '$firstName'
        }
      }
    },
    $project: {
      lastNames: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $exists: [false] },
          then: '',
          else: '$lastName'
        }
      }
    },
    $project: {
      fullName: {
        $concat: ['$firstNames', ' ', '$lastNames']
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to replace initial values with defaults. The [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) operator allows you to return an empty string when there's no value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            firstname: { $ifNull: [ "$firstname", "" ] },
            lastname: { $ifNull: [ "$lastname", "" ] },
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            fullName: { $trim: { input: { $concat: [ "$firstname", " ", "$lastname" ] } } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nv-fGcPgtsq)

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Mongo 5.3`, it's a nice use case for the new [`$fill`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/fill/#fill-missing-field-values-with-a-constant-value) aggregation operator:

```
// { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" }
// { firstName: "John" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $fill: { output: { firstName: { value: "John" }, lastName: { value: "Doe" } } } },
  { $set: { fullName: { $concat: ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"] } } }
])
// { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", fullName: "John Smith" }
// { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe",   fullName: "John Doe" }
```

Missing values or values set to `null` are `fill`ed with the given constant (for instance `Doe` for last names).